# qmake is not reading my .pro correctly

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

Recently I notice a compilation problem in one of my projects (see some comments about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880347/strange-type-of-multiple-definition-of-error), but notice it's not necessary to read that post). After some work, I did managed to find the problem: it would seem my qmake is not reading my .pro file accordingly, more specifically in a given moment where a include some specific libs under "debug" or "release" scope:

```
win32 {
    LIBS += -lpsapi

    debug {
        LIBS += C:/Qt/Qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwtd.dll \
            $${MLOGGER}/build/debug/mLogger.dll \      
            $${MSHARE_LIB}/build/debug/mShareLib.dll  
        DEFINES += DEBUG
    }

    release {
        LIBS += C:/Qt/Qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.dll \
            $${MLOGGER}/build/release/mLogger.dll \
            $${MSHARE_LIB}/build/release/mShareLib.dll
        DEFINES += RELEASE \
           QT_NO_DEBUG \
           QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
    }
} # win32
```

In accordance to the Qt Assistant, the above code should be valid. Here is one of the examples of nested scopes that Qt Assistant provides as a valid code:

```
win32 {
    debug {
        CONFIG += console
    }
}
```

What could be wrong? :( I have no idea. I don't remember finding any configuration in Qt Creator or somewhere else where such "qmake feature" was disabled.

I'm glad for any help.

Momergil

Comment: See [How to set different qmake configuration depending on debug / release?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5134245/26449) and [QMake CONFIG() function and 'active configuration'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18164490/26449)

Comment: @Bill thanks for the reply. I'll try this alternative option.

Comment: @Bill well it certainly did work :) Thanks for the comment, but I'll maintain the question open so someone may appear exaplaining why the show method didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes and the CONFIG variable are closely related. As you can read in the [manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-language.html#configuration-and-scopes):

> The values stored in the CONFIG variable are treated specially by
>   qmake. Each of the possible values can be used as the condition for a
>   scope.

So using a *debug* scope is equivalent to testing if *debug* is placed into the CONFIG variable. And using a *release* scope is equivalent to testing if *release* is placed into the CONFIG variable. **Unfortunately the CONFIG variable can contain conflicting options, such as both *release* and *debug*!** It is not enough to know if *debug* is in CONFIG or *release* is in CONFIG because both can be in CONFIG. What you need to know is which option is the **active**. Further explanation can be found in here: [QMake CONFIG() function and 'active configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18164490/26449).

Comment: thanks Bill for the full explanation :) It really makes sense (quite unfortunately the Qt Assistant files doesn't address this point, at least AFAIK).